# Dropdown selector, selected option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

I am using Ruby on Rails version 3. I have defined the following helper method for a selector:

```
  def current_user_selector
    collection_select(:user, :id, User.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => "Select a User"});
  end
```

I have introduced the aforementioned selector in my `index.html.erb`:

```
...
<%= current_user_selector %>
...
```

I've read somewhere that the selected option from the dropdown menu could be accessed in the controller with:

```
selected_user = params[user][id]
```

I have added the above line in several actions of my controller but I keep getting exceptions.

Currently I have it in the following action:

```
  # GET /users/:id/click
  # GET /users/:id/click.xml
  def click
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users_to_click = User.where("clicks_given - clicks_received >= ?", -5).order("clicks_given - clicks_received")
    selected_user = params[user][id]

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # click.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
    end
  end
```

My question is, how and I get the selected user of the dropdown menu.

Naren Sisodiya led me to the following exception:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
```

Comment: can you put form where you are using dropdown?

Comment: The dropdown menu is being rendered in the `index.html.erb`. It is in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

params[:user][:id] will give you id of selected user, so you need to find the user using this id.

```
selected_user = User.find(params[:user][:id])
```

**EDIT:**

also make sure that you are accessing it as params[:user][:id] instead params[user][id]

**Update:**

you need to pass the selected value to server, as you mentioned you have a button that invokes the click action. Now you can create a from with dropdown and one submit button; something as

```
<%= form_tag('/click',:method=>'get') do -%>
 <%= current_user_selector %>
 <%= submit_tag 'Get Selected' %>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: It didn't work. See my question above for the error returned.

Comment: If your drop-down is being render in index file then how are you passing its selected value to server? you need to pass it to server. and when your click action is being called?

Comment: On the index file I have a button that invokes the click action. How do I pass the selected value to the server?

Comment: you can create a form which includes the dropdown and your button, the button would be submit button of form. The form action should map with your click action.

Comment: It's me again, wouldn't it be possible to generate the dropdown menu with JS and get the selected user with JS? Avoiding the form submission. It's because the current user is also used by another butting that calls the click action. I have uploaded my application to github (https://github.com/TiagoVeloso/clicker/tree/master/app) so you can see what is being used.